# The reverse method should print out lst in reverse. It prints an empty arrayList instead. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Tags: java, recursion, reverse

This is the class with the buildList method which builds the in

```
class Recursive 
{
    public static ArrayList<Integer> reversedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static ArrayList<Integer> buildList(int n)//builds the arrayList based on integer. If the int is 5 then the contents are 1,2,3,4,5.
    {
        // write this in terms of a recursive call using a smaller n        
        ArrayList<Integer> tempList = null;
        if (n <= 0) // The smallest list we can make
        {  
        return new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

        }
        else // All other size lists are created here
        {

        tempList= buildList(n-1);
        tempList.add(n);
        }



        return tempList;

    }
```

This is the problem method. Idk why it returns [], I think there is a passing error.

```
    public static ArrayList<Integer> reverse(ArrayList<Integer> lst)//the problem method
    {
        if(lst.size()<=0) {

        }
        else {
            reversedList.add(lst.remove(lst.size()-1)); 
            reverse(lst);

        }
        return reversedList;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> lst = Recursive.buildList(5);
        System.out.println(lst);
        reverse(lst);
        System.out.println(lst);


    }

}
```

The reverse method removes the last item of lst and adds it to the empty reversedList. After the first iteration the contents should be [5]. Second [5,4]...all the way to [5,4,3,2,1]. But somehow it ends up being [].
So the reverse method is supposed to print out [5,4,3,2,1] but rather prints []. I think it has something to do with passing the reversedList between the if and else statement but I'm not sure.

Comment: You print out the original list, which now has no items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the original list **lst** only which is now empty as program has removed all the elements.

You must reassign the **lst** to new object reference returned from function like **lst = reverse(lst);**

OR you can use **System.out.println(reversedList)**

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> lst = Recursive.buildList(5);
        System.out.println(lst);
        lst = reverse(lst);                   ////update lst reference

        System.out.println(lst);
        System.out.println(reversedList);    //// OR print reversedList directly 
    }
```

Hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much. So since the lst variable has all its objects removed I have to reassign it to the reverse(lst) so that it will equal the reverseList and therefore have its contents?

Comment: Yes. With that both lst and reverseList will refer to same object